# "Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" when AjaxToolKit in Bin folder

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm learning ASP.net and working on a project in Visual Studio 2008. When I originally installed the AjaxControlToolKit I unzipped to a folder on my desktop, added a tab to the toolbox and browsed to the dll on my desktop. Everything worked fine until I realized the problem I had created.

I'm now trying to move the toolkit to my bin folder. I deleted the tab on my toolbox, deleted the reference to the AjaxControlToolKit on my desktop, unzipped to my bin folder and added a new tab with the correct path to the dll. When I run the project I receive an error:

"ASP.NET runtime error: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded."

The problem only seems to occur when the ajax dll is located in my bin folder. I made another folder in my project and unzipped the toolkit there and everything worked fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem today and I got fixed it after checking every 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage reference in my all project solutions references or project solution references.

Must have to have same version of all, then it should be fine.

Try it and let me know.